# PyScripter won't update my imports

Tags: python, pyscripter

I am using portable python 1.1 with python 2.6.2. The PyScriptor is 1.9.9.6. I open all the files I am working on with PyScriptor. So, I run my main file and an error shows up with code in one of my imported files. I fix it and run the main file again, but the same error shows up. It is as if the imported file is still the old one but PyScriptor is correctly saving the files I edit. Restarting PyScriptor fixes it, but is a pain to do that for every bug. I tested this happens bu adding a print statement that showed up after restarting, and then removing it and still see the print statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reload(imported_module_name)` in the interactive shell to reload the module before re-running your script. PyScripter does everything in a single Python instance, which makes debugging easier, but also, as you discovered, makes fixing imported files a bit trickier.

You can also completely reinitialize the Remote Engine from the Run menu to get a fresh interpreter.